# Get access token for google by using Python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, access-token, google-oauth

Trying to get the access token in response for google but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is what I've done so far:

```py
import requests

authorization_code_req = {
    'client_id':'key',
    'client_secret':'key',
    'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:5000',
    'grant_type':'authorization_code'}

r = requests.get('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                 params=authorization_code_req)

print (r)
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: <Response [401]>

Answer (score 1):

you should send `authorization_code_req` as `json` and not as `params`. So your code should look something like this:

```
import requests

authorization_code_req = {
    'client_id':'key',
    'client_secret':'key',
    'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:5000',
    'grant_type':'authorization_code'
}

r = requests.get('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
                 json=authorization_code_req)

print(r)
```

Comment: Still not working:- 
{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'}

Comment: sahil lamba did you ever figured out how to get the google token

Comment: {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'} this is because of the invalid redirect_uri. Please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

# Load service account credentials
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/credentials.json' #service account credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage']  # Replace with desired scopes
)
# Generate access token
auth_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(auth_request)
access_token = credentials.token
print('Access Token:', access_token)
```

This will generate access token:

```
Access Token: ya29.c.*****************
```